# nth root of huge integer number in sage

Tags: sagemath

I have been reading for the last hour about different ways to take an nth root in sage. I am having trouble finding a way to do so for very large numbers.

Any help would be much appreciated. I have tried ^(1/n) and pow and a number of others.

Comment: x^(1/n), x**(1/n), or pow(x,1/n) should all work.  If the problem is that you want a concrete number rather than a symbolic expression, try n(x^(1/n)) to find the approximate numerical value of an expression.  You might also want to run tutorial() to open a browser window with the tutorial.

Comment: When I do those it just appends ^(1/5) for example to my number... It doesn't actually do the operation.

Comment: This is my number 383359376317228026832765614031101780857214373741934853796883469684751393959423303934031779306976105234618634914722122231966050161090557311139688754390702005669975825514220776140658553598335180339644221202109745240693646681489614040361698983885974381266138822986136754230956173498395067036601233601299698337833849969027885834924082799260330843401454066113756946449729494314541583444719025620597701816509274146453

Comment: This is M^(1/5)

Comment: 383359376317228026832765614031101780857214373741934853796883469684751393959423303934031779306976105234618634914722122231966050161090557311139688754390702005669975825514220776140658553598335180339644221202109745240693646681489614040361698983885974381266138822986136754230956173498395067036601233601299698337833849969027885834924082799260330843401454066113756946449729494314541583444719025620597701816509274146453^(1/5)

Comment: See also https://ask.sagemath.org/question/35102/nth-root-of-huge-number/

Comment: @kcrisman that is my post on that site too. There are no answers yet.

Comment: @ryBear - yes, I just try to help cross-ref for people searching later.

Comment: And I will post my answer in both places though it may not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

If you are looking for a numerical approximation, there are several routes open to you.  Here are two.

- You can approximate after taking it with e.g. `a.n(digits=100)`, like [here](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVkb1OBEEMg3sk3uHKuwby68TFvQrSISR0DQ28v_AUuzvRxPaX7ONyv-RmNnOQPhFrgc0YNLws3c1nbXvCKyennFnbOcRuFvSpaU8mmxWZpuMRzjANHLh1qNEXWfRShkdEOgFrc93TukdRcpHpdCVtLMwaIKc3ur0ibOZAobdbyIfb11KqquNqIa-pDvUwUcB6LY9GRHBwJdptNeV6AK4qgqsDlBtp1Nwj0NU8hpEM5hrrvEmc0NGzdQqLkZvWQEVuDBkQj21pBV4tDmiqabDEyAkWK8-NH1nVuEwaYWIa83W0MbRl9Xe-vnzqBz0-rv7eNxVvP9ev5_fz7_fuZrd_hoFcbQ==&lang=sage)
- You can use a decimal point like `383.` instead of `383` and [then do the root](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwVkLttGEAMQ_sA2cFl3CT6kmLhVQJ4_yXMK-6HE8knfX98ffR1r5roZNVF4bqIRU50ZiQvblk5zeakem6bwl0PfAw3W63VVHf4-oSkOiAiY8uFeehRjjOyqjoFxEb6X7FLR9nFptxpBaMiFpC4V7s5VUE-KOztGvlx50VbNfNco-zF2XKNGgNczulpTISEzqK7dVFfFpB-Vel8gXOrQ-6bBj33E6BliHRbb5fwQul18x5RtJvHIEdeUSqYJ248gpw1B9wVFxoziqXR9PvJJ5th2mRRYSZGXmJD5Sm7fvvv71_f___kv_38AYMsVwQ=&lang=sage)

More advanced options include setting a "real field" with a certain accuracy like `R=RealField(1000)` and using that ...

Comment: There's also `nth_root` function and method, and `real_nth_root` https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/functions/sage/functions/other.html#sage.functions.other.Function_real_nth_root